# Are two smaller septic tanks equivalent to one large tank?

Tags: plumbing, septic, septic-tanks

Related: [How often do septic tanks typically need to be pumped?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/how-often-do-septic-tanks-typically-need-to-be-pumped)

Our home has two 800 gallon tanks next to each other, from the previous plumbers drawing it looks like they are connected.  [image: http://imgur.com/dSSZwiy]

I was looking at http://www.nesc.wvu.edu/pdf/WW/publications/pipline/PL_FA95.pdf

And they say 1500 gallons for 2 people should be pumped every 9.1 years.  Should I use that guide for my combined tank size or should I follow whatever is closer to 800 gallons?

Comment: What's a "grauge?"

Comment: Check out this answer here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/1712/928  It sounds like you have a 800 gallon septic tank, and an 800 gallon grey water tank.  Which means you should pump for 800, not 1600.  Also check if you have a weeping tile bed.  The second tank could be a holding tank  only, and will need to be pumped when full (Rare. I've only seen this in rocky terrain where a tile bed is impossible).

Comment: A terrible misspelling of garage, not my drawing :)

Comment: @chriscudmore  Looks like an answer, walks like an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this answer here: [diy.stackexchange.com/a/1712/928](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/1712/928)

It sounds like you have a 800 gallon septic tank, and an 800 gallon black water tank. Which means you should pump for 800, not 1600.

Cautionary note:

In some rare circumstances, most notably the rocky lake district of Muskoka in Ontario, weeping beds are illegal (lake water contamination), and the second tank is actually a holding tank.  In this situation, you need to pump out the tank fairly often, or it will fill up and overflow.

If you have a nice lawn that stays green without watering in the dog days of summer, then you most likely have a weeping tile bed.